# Not able to add '1' in prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print lis as '1 2 3...'. But it prints '0 1 2...'.

```
var lessss = $('.lesson-nav .mod.unit.less li').length;

    for (var i = 0; i < lessss; i++) {
        $('.lesson-nav .mod.unit.less li:eq('+i+')').prepend('<i>'+i+'</i><b>L'+i+'</b>');
        console.log(i);
    }
```

Comment: Because your for loop starts with 0 and not 1. do var i=1; i<=lessss; i++

Comment: Starting at 0 look at your for loop

Comment: Using i = 1 is not solving problem. It doesn't apply .prepend to first li.

Comment: Use addition to add `1` to `i`. Are you really asking how to do addition JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < lessss; i++) {
    $('.lesson-nav .mod.unit.less li').eq(i).prepend('<i>'+(i+1)+'</i><b>L'+(i+1)+'</b>');
    console.log(i+1);
}
```

Or Simply replace all your code with:

```
$('.lesson-nav .mod.unit.less li').each(function(i,v) {
    $(this).prepend( '<i>'+(i+1)+'</i><b>L'+(i+1)+'</b>' );
    console.log(i+1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add 1 to the value when printing it out, it's should be as easy as this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < lessss; i++) {
    $('.lesson-nav .mod.unit.less li:eq('+i+')').prepend('<i>'+(i+1)+'</i><b>L'+(i+1)+'</b>');
    console.log(i);
}
```

This will still enumerate all your li-elements correctly since `i` will stay zero-based but the actual text prepended will start at one.